# Applying dynamic program to a game?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider a game where the game board is a grid with `n` rows and `m` columns. You begin at the bottom left corner of the grid (assume this has coordinates `(0,0)`). You start with a score of `0`, and inventory space `I > 0`.

At each cell of the grid there may be one of two things, the cell is either empty, or contains some loot. Loot has a size `x` and value `v`, you can think of each potential piece of loot being indexed by the cell, i.e. `L(i,j)` = `(x(i,j), v(i,j))`, where `L(i,j) = (0, 0)` if the cell is empty.

From cell `(i, j)` the player can move up `1` row to one of three cells, `(i + 1, j − 1)`, `(i + 1, j)`, or `(i + 1, j + 1)`. The player cannot move back down the rows or move side to side. When the player reaches a cell with loot they can either choose to take it or leave it. Taking it the loot decreases the players inventory space by the size `x`, while increasing their score by the value `v`.

---

How would a dynamic programming algorithm apply to this?

I figure that the subproblems would be moving up the row, where as long as there is a row above, and one of the left/right each. It would choose whichever one has the highest value `v` and fits in our inventory `x`, otherwise it just leaves it.